# Scheme fonction

Tags: algorithm, scheme

I have a question about a scheme fonction:

```
> (let ((x 2) (y 3))
>         (let ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
>               (* z x) ) )
```

The result is: 35. Can someone explain me why?
What I don't understand is that we change the value of x to 7 and in my opinion the result should be 70.

Comment: I don't know scheme/racket, but there's a part in their docs that mirrors your question. You may be able to find an answer there: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html.

Comment: Why? `x` is `2` and `y` is `3` in the outer `let` body and thus `x` becomes `7` and `z` becomes `(+ x y) ; ==> 5` in the inner `let` body. The bindings are only valid in the body so `z` doesn't exist until `(* z x) ; ==> 35` and `x` doesn't have it's shadowed value until the body either so it's the old value until the multiplication expression. The expression is the same as `((λ (x y)
   ((λ (x z) (* z x))
    7 (+ x y)))
 2 3)` which shows the scope better. If you do `let*` instead it's like each variable has its own `let` and then it will be `70`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Sylwester, explained it already.

```
; I like to write `let` forms in this way:
(let ((x 2)
      (y 3))
  (let ((x 7)
        (z (+ x y))) ; since this is within a `let` definition part,
                     ; and not in a `let*` definition part, 
                     ; the definition of z - which is (+ x y) - 
                     ; cannot "see" (x 7) yet,
                     ; so it "searches" for x and "finds" it above 
                     ; in the let definition (x 2).
                     ; therefore, (z (+ x y)) will be evaluated as 
                     ; (z (+ 2 3)) thus (z 5)
    (* z x)))        ; this now is in the inner-let body,
                     ; thus it "sees" (x 7) which has "shadowed" (x 2)
                     ; therefore this will be evaluated as (* 5 7), thus 35.
```

Answer (score 0):

The definitions in a `let`-form can't refer to earlier bindings in the same `let`-form; bindings are looked up in its surrounding environment.
Thus, `x` is `2` in `(+ x y)`, and `7` in `(* z x)`.

To put it another way,

```
(let ((a e1) (b e2))
    e3)
```

is not equivalent to

```
((lambda (a) ((lambda (b) e3) e2)) e1)
```

but to

```
((lambda (a b) e3) e1 e2)
```

You would get the behaviour you expect if you used `let*`.